# Why should a background thread run and then stop in a second?Should it run forever?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I read the book called **Effective Java 2** in the item 66, it say that the  background thread will run forever and never stop. But when I run the code in my computer, it stop in a second? What's wrong? is it the computer cache problem?

```
public class StopThread {
  private static boolean stopRequested;

  public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException {
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (!stopRequested) {
          i++;
          System.out.println(i+";");
        }
      } 
    });
    backgroundThread.start(); 
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    stopRequested = true;
  }
}
```

The books suggest to use `Synchronize` or `volatile`, but I try and find that even  I do not use the suggestion, it runs in a second in my computer. But run forever in my roommate. He say that it is the reason about cache config.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Uhh, but you stop the thread after a second? `while (!stopRequested)` runs until `stopRequested = true;` which happens after `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` - wait 1 second then stop the thread.

Comment: ..........seriously

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler,I do not stop the thread.It stops automatically.

Comment: You change the state of stopRequested to true, the while loop is written to exit when this state occurs, and on exit this will stop the thread. What confuses you?

Comment: You code is not expected to run the same always. It may stop as it does for you. Or it may not stop at all because your `stopRequested` is not volatile and update on it in one thread may not get reflected in another.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels,the book say that stopRequested can not be changed to the backgroud from main method,so that it alway run forever.

Comment: That is not necessarily so as @Codebender notes.

Comment: What happens to the second thread when main exits? Try adding something like a ...sleep(5) after setting stopRequested = true; , to see if the second thread continues to run during that 5 second sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Bloch, author of Effective Java, says is "*in the absence of synchronization, there is no guarantee as to when, if ever, the background thread will see the change in the value stop-Requested* [SIC]".

That is to say, it might stop immediately.  Or it might stop after a short time.  Or it might stop never.  It is not *required* to run forever.  For that matter the compiler is not even required to remove the synchronization.  But it can.  And it very well might.  And so you that is where "volatile" keyword comes in.

Answer (score 0):

You've added a line to the original example:

```
System.out.println(i+";");
```

`PrintStream.println(String)` contains a `synchronized` block, which has similar memory consistency effects to `volatile`.

Comment: no, not really. it won't synchronize because only one thread is printing to STDOUT.

Comment: @glee8e Well, it definitely forces a read barrier on the background thread. The write probably gets flushed when the main thread ends.

Comment: @glee8e The `println()` is, in fact, the change that makes this "work." The absence of guaranteed behavior does not guarantee absence of behavior under the JMM.

Comment: sad thing though, the program runs forever on PO's roommate's computer. That synchronized block establish no happens-before relationship between that pair of read and write.